Hohenberg and Kohn second-order energy correction
In their seminal paper 'Inhomogeneous Electron Gas', Hohenberg and Kohn assert in equation (33) that the change of energy up to the second order is
$$E=E_0+\frac{\lambda^2(4\pi)^2}{\Omega}\sum_{\vec{q}}\frac{|a(\vec{q})|^2}{q^4}\sum_{n}\frac{\langle 0|\hat{\rho}_q|n\rangle\langle n|\hat{\rho}_{-q}|0\rangle}{E_0-E_n}.$$
I have a couple of issues with this equation (in the following I'll be using the same notation as this answer):

I don't quite understand why the first order term, $\langle\psi_0|\delta\hat{H}|\psi_0\rangle$, should vanish

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, this issue is already discussed in the linked answer.
By applying second order perturbation theory, e.g. like in Ballentine, the second term should be
$$\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{E_0-E_n}\langle\psi_0|\biggl[-4\pi\frac{\lambda}{V}\sum_q\frac{a(\vec{q})}{q^2}\hat{\rho}_q\biggr]|\psi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|\biggl[-4\pi\frac{\lambda}{V}\sum_{q'}\frac{a(\vec{q}')}{q'^2}\hat{\rho}_{q'}\biggr]|\psi_0\rangle$$
which I don't see how it could be manipulated into the provided result without additional assumptions, e.g. RPA, that don't seem to be mentioned in the text



I don't know what you are asking, because in the link that you gave, they had the answer to your question. You need to know that $q^\prime=-q$ somewhere. The linked answer covered this.

The formula you give for the second-order perturbation correction cannot stand as it is. A term depends on $E_n$ out of the summation on $n$.

thanks @naturallyInconsistent, I clearly overlooked that.
That only applies to the second of the points, right? I don't see how what is argued in the linked answer would allow the first-order correction to vanish

thanks @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, I edited the equation so that the $E_n$ term is inside the summation

IIRC we are doing self-consistency, where the algorithm only stops when the first order correction is zeroed. Or that there is some divergence if you don't zero the first order term. I think you will get a far better treatment if you just referred to a textbook that covers DFT. This is a big enough subject area that there are nice textbooks now.
